# В блуждающих поисках php-фреймворка

Tags: фреймворк, php, безопасность, mvc

В поисках лёгкого *(синоним - минималистичный)* php-фреймворка *(или, может, даже класса безопасности для сайта)* для одного проекта, минимальные требования:

1. Безопасность.

Дополнительно, но не важно:

1. Админка (простейшая).
2. Простой роутинг.
3. ЧПУ.

---

Всё остальное по ТЗ выходит за рамки фреймворка.
Собственные поиски не привели к вразумительному решению, ищу максимально безопасный (до адекватной паранойи).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете подобрать что-то из микро-фреймворков:

[Flight](http://flightphp.com)

[Slim](http://www.slimframework.com)

[FatFree](http://fatfreeframework.com)

[Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org)

[PHPixie](http://phpixie.com)

Мне самому нравится [wei php](https://github.com/twinh/wei), но есть минус, это то, что полная документация на Китайском языке. :)

Comment: Пока смотрю на silex.

Answer (score 1):

Лучший фреймворк Laravel можно использовать lite версию - Lumen

Comment: не смотря на то что вопрос успели закрыть из-за его холиварности темы, спасибо, обязательно посмотрю.